# Filter View With Criteria Ac cross Multiple Columns or some other solution

Tags: google-sheets

I am struggling to find a solution either for the Filter view or using the slicer that would give me some sort of an OR function.

My spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

I need the Filter view it to show the client if they had any appointment 1st, 2nd, etc... that happened in a certain month.

Comment: It doesn't look like the photo posted. Column 1 is the client name, Column 2 is the date of the 1st appt, Column 3 is whether or not we met with the client or it cancelled / no showed. Then the 2nd and 3rd columns are a repeat for the 2nd appointment if that makes sense.

Comment: Hey @Aaron, can you link your sheet or a dummy one with sample data here ? even some formula with what you tried can be good for us ! Right now we can't see your screenshots (new contributor don't have this privilege )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FILTERS VIEW` for column `A` you use:

```
=OR((MONTH(B2)=8),(MONTH(D2)=8),(MONTH(F2)=8))
```

You apply the above formula in the range: `A1:Z`
This will only show rows that the month from the dates in columns `B` OR `D` OR `F` is the 8th month (August). We use [MONTH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052?hl=en-GB) TO EXTRACT the month from the given dates

**Tip**: You could also use:


```
=(MONTH(B2)=8)+(MONTH(D2)=8)+(MONTH(F2)=8)
```

Comment: THANKS!!!!! That worked perfect!

Comment: @AaronHalvorson As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.